# Implementing timer into Pygame game

Tags: timer

I'm new to Pygame. For a class assignment, I decided to make the game of Wormy from a tutorial. After I finished making the basic game, I decided to implement some new features into it.

A simple feature I want to implement is a very basic "loading" screen at the beginning of the game, which consists of a large blue screen with "Loading" printed on it. Then comes the tricky part: I would like to make another line of text appear after 10 seconds the "Loading" text showed up on screen. I was thinking of implementing some form of timer into it, but the code (see below) won't work. Does any of you have any ideas? Any ideas would be highly appreciated.

```
FPS = 8 # Already declared at the beginning
.
.
.
def showStartScreen(): # Start screen function that is to be called in  
main()     
    loadingFont = pygame.font.SysFont('centurygothic', 50)
    loadingText = loadingFont.render('Loading...', True, WHITE)
    tick_counter = 0

    while True:
        pygame.time.Clock.tick(FPS)
        tick_counter += 1
        DISPLAYSURF.fill(DEEPSKYBLUE)
        DISPLAYSURF.blit(loadingText, (WINDOWWIDTH / 2 - 
          loadingText.get_width() // 2, 235))
        if tick_counter >= 40:
            drawPressKeyMsg()
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.wait(1000)
            checkForKeyPress() # clear out any key presses in the event 
              queue
            if checkForKeyPress():
                pygame.event.get() # clear event queue
                return
            pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: When it starts 'loading', set a variable at the current time. Each frame, check if the current time is greater than that variable + 10. Also, I did a timer in my own small game where I added the frame time to a value (like at 60fps that's 0.017s), and it still remained accurate as far as I could tell.

Comment: @Peter: Would you mind sending me your timer from your own game?

Comment: Well, I can point to the bits I guess. `GameTime` is the class I made for keeping fps and ticks separate. Line 3018 is the countdown code. Basically, if I set to 60 ticks per second, and I want 100 seconds, I say that's 6000 ticks. `ticks` in `GameTime` is the number of ticks that have happened in the last frame, so each frame I remove those ticks from the total, until it hits zero. I set it to redraw when it goes down by a second. That'll be why it's accurate, I'd forgotten that I did that :P - https://github.com/Peter92/Connect3D/blob/master/Connect3D.py

Comment: OK, thanks. I think I'll need quite a bit of time to digest the code provided in your link. :)

Comment: @Peter: If I were to start timing when it starts "loading", should I create a separate timer function, then?

Comment: You'd just need to have some way of getting how long the frame has been. A possibility is at the start of each frame, do `current_time = time.time()`, and at the end, do `last_time = current_time`. Then, when it starts loading, set a variable to 10, and each frame, subtract `current_time - last_time`. It'll be less accurate than using the ticks but won't require any other functions :)

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll try that out. :)